# Specifying a character set in HTTP headers

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, http-headers

When using Google PageSpeed tester, I get the following:

> The following resources have no character set specified in their HTTP headers. Specifying a character set in HTTP headers can speed up browser rendering.
>   http://www.ntainc.com/

I have searched everywhere, and can't seem to figure out why it isn't "reading" my charset.  I have it listed in the html document header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

And in my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and there is an .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

I believe our server is an IIS. What am I missing?

Comment: What are you missing?  You forgot to tell us what symptoms you have.

Answer (score 4):

The warning is referring to the HTTP `Content-Type` header. It is being sent by your webserver to the client like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

It needs to be sent like this instead:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

You need to check your webserver configuration.  Your `.htaccess` addition should be adding the `charset` attribute to the header, but apparently is not.  So either you put it in the wrong `.htaccess` file, or the server is ignoring it.

The fact that your HTML contains a `<meta charset>` tag is irrelevant to the warning, as the HTML is just arbitrary data inside of the HTTP response body (though it does allow an HTML5-enabled client to process your UTF-8 encoded HTML correctly).

Your `web.config` charset is irrelevant, as it is only interpreted by your webserver, not a client.

Comment: I will check when I get in the office on Monday.  I know the .htaccess file says:  AddDefaultCharset utf-8.   Mabe it's written incorrectly?

Comment: My .htaccess file does indeed say AddDefaultCharset utf-8.  I was wondering if I have the wrong syntax?